# disable customers to checkout in magento below a specific range

Tags: magento

If customers purchase more than  X Rs (X may be 1000), then only he would be able to check out.How to do this  in magento. is there any extension availaible or we have to edit in source code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do with Login as admin,

then go to `System->configuration`,

then select `Sales` from left Nav and click on `Minimum order amount`.

Also Then select Yes from Enable dropdown, enter Minimum order amount,

enter message and also enter error message that will be shown whenever the order will be less

than specific range at the shopping cart.

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: @user3089849, glad to help you. will you please accept my answer. so some one can trust our thread and use for future reference .